# Overriding Rails route helpers for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a classic blog application with comments and posts. 
In this application comments are always nested under a post.

```
GET /posts/:posts_id/comments/:id ...
```

I want to in some way override the URL helpers so that I could them as if comments was not a nested resource.

**Requirements**:

The comments should ONLY use nested urls:

```
/posts/:posts_id/comments/:id
```

I should be able to do:

```
comments_path @comment
```

And

```
redirect_to @comment
```

**I have tried**:

I can get Rails to generate the route helpers without the prefix with:

```
resources :posts
scope '/posts/:post_id' do
  resources :comments
end
```

But `comments_path(@comment)` would still give me  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` as `post_id` is not set.

I could of course manually create my own helper methods but I would like rails to generate the helpers if possible.

From my understanding the routes helpers are a veneer around `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`. I have been looking into `ActionDispatch::RoutingPolymorphicRoutes` but I can't find how the generated helpers "serialize" an model instance into params.

Is it possible to create a model method which is used when the routes helper turns the comment resource into params?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of `to_param`.

Comment: Why not you try something like this !!!

`resources :posts
resources :comments`,  without `scope`.

Comment: @jonsnow thanks but you obviously don't understand the question. That  would give me `user_comments_path` and I would need to supply the id and the post_id.

Comment: I am aware that there are other solutions such as using decorators but I want to know if its possible to create an override on the model level so that I can use the out of box helpers.

Comment: if you don't care about your posts routes you can do resources :posts, :as => "" do
  resources :comments
end

but obv its silly.

Comment: Actually @osman that gives Pythoneske route helpers like `_comments` and  `edit__comment`. Using `scope` as I have done above does give the correct routes and helper name.

Comment: How would you differentiate between multiple parents for 'comments', eg. `/users/:id/comments` and `posts/:id/comments`?

Comment: Thats a very good point @fylooi. I had not thought of that.

Comment: I guess you could look at the params and see if there is a `users_id` param or a `posts_id` param. But I think I might scrap the idea completely.

Comment: Thats if you did it with helpers like in sevenseacats answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar requirements to this before, and what I've done is simply create a custom helper method in my `ApplicationController` like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def comment_path(comment)
    post_comment_path(comment.post, comment)
  end

  helper_method :comment_path
end
```

That way, you can still use `comment_path` in your views, helpers, controllers, etc. but it uses the full nested route instead.

I don't know if it can be done with Rails internals, but quite simply I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: This is a viable option but I was hoping to avoid having to create `comments_path`, `comments_url`, `new_comment_path` etc if I wanted the full kit of routes helpers. Maybe I can create a helper which uses metaprogramming to do the code generation for me.

Comment: Having some of those routes is impossible. How can you have `new_comment_path` when you have comments nested under posts - you have to provide the post in that scenario, you don't have a comment to derive it from. The easiest thing for you to might just be to change your URL structure - it sounds like you don't want them to be nested, or maybe you're looking for shallow nesting? See section 2.7.2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I think you are wrong there `new_comment_path = new_post_comment_path(post_id: post.to_param)`

Comment: that makes a big assumption that you have a variable called `post` defined - I wouldn't want that kind of implicit assumption in my code.

Comment: Sorry it would be `new_comment_path(Post.find(55))`

Comment: that's really not a good idea, it bucks all kinds of Rails conventions.

Comment: I guess you are right in that shallow nesting is the Rails way to do it, I was mostly asking from a hypothetical point of view - if I had to only have nested routes how would I be able to use the helpers as if it where a non nested resource. I think you're right in that it would mostly be confusing in having a new_comments_path helper with arguments than the defaults.